# read cv::Mat from Matlab's .mat in python get different results compared to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

Reading `cv::Mat` from Matlab's `.mat` in python get different results compared to Matlab , as follow

```
import scipy.io as sio  
import numpy as np
data = sio.loadmat('image.mat')
img = data['img']
cv2.imshow('img', img)
```

the image as follows:

[image: the result using python to read mat]

but in matlab:

```
image = load('image.mat')
imshow(image.img)
```

the result as follow:

[image]

it seems that the python has wrong with parseing the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with default color conventions of Matlab and OpenCV, OpenCV uses `BGR` color convention instead of `RGB` color space, So in order to get your image displayed properly you need to swap the B and R channels, There are multiple ways to do this, as per OpenCV it can be done as:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Comment: thanks, it solve my question!